# Unusual 'Headers already sent' error. No whitespace nor changing of the header

Tags: php, wordpress, header, http-headers, http-post

Before you start telling me there are already 10000000 posts on this error, I know.

I am working on a wordpress plugin and am recieving the following error when submitting my edit pages:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ***\wp-content\plugins\***\meta-class-load.php:1067) in ***\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 934
```

What's different about this error is the line it references does not interface with the header, nor output content before. I have checked for whitespace surrounding php tags, and there is none :P

This is the contents (and surrounds) of line 1067:

```
        $name = $field['id'];
        $type = $field['type'];
        $old  = $this->get_meta($post->ID, $field); // THIS IS THE LINE
        $new = isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : ($field['multiple'] ? array() : '');
```

Any ideas or solutions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Have you re-saved any of these mentioned files on your computer? Could be a byte-order-mark you can't see at the start of a file. If you're comfortable with it, open a command line, telnet to port 80 of your web server, hand write an HTTP request to the blog, and look at the output. See what's in the response before the error message, that'd be the output that shouldn't be there.

Comment: You're also correct, other errors were being output before the header error, thus meaning the headers were already sent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never output anything before sending the `HEADER`, if you do so you will not be able to send the header and it will throw an error !
It's also a good practice to set `error_reporting(0)` on production server to make sure that no error gets shown before `header`

Comment: I think that it might be errors displaying before the header as you mentioned. Some were displaying before the 'Headers already sent' error. I'll quickly test with error reporting off and see if it works.

Comment: The page loads once I have turned off error reporting, so it looks like that was indeed the issue, Thanks. Although, It is rather important I turn on error reporting while developing for obvious reasons. Errors on other pages don't seem to cause the header error, so any ideas what in specific would cause this?

Comment: Don't worry, got it figured :)
Is there any way to mark a question as solved on StackOverflow?

Comment: look at the left side of the answer, click on the tick mark, it will be green then.

Comment: @Toby you can also give people who answered a +1 vote if you found their answer helpful by clicking on the little up arrow, including the one you accepted I believe.

Comment: @Mike I'm new to StackOverflow so don't have enough reputation to upvote yet :(
Oh Well.

Answer (score 0):

1067 is the line that outputs content. Line 934 is the one setting the header. I think you have them backwards.

Comment: Line 934 is within a different file. So that's not the issue, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Line 934 of wp-includes\pluggable.php is trying to send a page header, however content was already sent to the browser from meta-class-load.php line 1067, so therefore you can't send any more headers.

Comment: OK, sorry, I had misunderstood your answer. Turns out that my php was causing other errors that were output to the page, leading to the 'headers already sent' error.

Answer (score 0):

No output can be sent before all headers are sent. One of the files listed in the error, or possibly a file included by one of those files, is outputting something.  It could be something intentional, a stray bit of white space, a warning or an error message.

To prevent the error you can try calling either ob_clean(); or ob_end_clean(); to clear the output buffer right before your header call. ob_end_clean(); is almost always successful in these cases.

Comment: The bit about the other error message was correct, however Sourav beat you to it :P. So I think I'll have to give it to him. Thanks!