# I want to download csv in wordpress admin page...it works fine at local server but live it give header already sent error

Tags: wordpress, csv, http-headers, localhost, administration

```
The code for download that works at localhost is but live at hostgather server it throughs error 


ob_get_clean();
    header("Content-type: text/x-csv"); # DECLARING FILE TYPE
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_file_name); # EXPORT GENERATED CSV FILE
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    echo $fields;
    exit;
```

The error is

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/londoner/public_html/pkfones.com/pinquest/wp-admin/includes/template.php:1679) in /home/londoner/public_html/pkfones.com/pinquest/wp-content/plugins/wp-gamesize/setgamesize_admin.php on line 131

Comment: Well, I am afraid you will have to tell use what those lines mentioned in the error message actually contain. That is what the error message is for: it shows exactly what line causes the output to be send.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unusual 'Headers not sent' error. No whitespace nor changing of the header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714991/unusual-headers-not-sent-error-no-whitespace-nor-changing-of-the-header)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're calling `ob_start()` at the beginning (or very close) of your code execution.  This will buffer all your output and allow you send headers any time.  You can probably just place this at the very top of your functions.php.

The reason this works on your local and not live is probably a difference in the server config, where locally you are buffering by default but not on live.  This is a good reason to make sure that your development and production environments are as similar as possible.